# go elastic bulk add and retrieve data

Tags: go, elasticsearch

How to bulk add array of User to elastic, and retrieve all data in go?

```
type User struct {
    UserID    int    
    Email     string 
    FirstName string 
    LastName  string 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `github.com/olivere/elastic`, you can find all of your needed operations right here: https://github.com/olivere/elastic/wiki/BulkIndex

The Wiki page of this repository is very very great for learning and using.

If you faced any problem or question using this repository, please tell me to help in coding.